# Android Alert Dialog Title under the Divider

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

My Alert Dialog has the title under the divider, how can i fix it? take a look at the pic

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);
builder.setMessage(stringhowtoplay)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setTitle("How to Play")
    .setPositiveButton("Entendi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    }});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzI0T.png)

Answer (score 0):

That is the default layout in Alert Dialog. you will have to create [custom layout Alert Dialog](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) to remove it.